# Need to removed url when printing the value of href in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am attempting to print the href value but its occuring along with the url

HTML

```
    <style>

        a.printable:link:after,

        a.printable:visited:after {
            content:" [" attr(href) "] ";
        }
    </style>



 <table>
            <tr>
                <td height="40" valign="right" style="width:150px; font-size: 4.2mm; padding:4pt 0pt 0.5pt 0pt; text-align:center; background:#006400;"><a href="{{ request.scheme|safe|escape }}://{{ request.get_host }}/crm/orders/accepting/{{client.id}}/{{invoice.id}}/" class="printable" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;">Accept this Order</a></td>

            </tr>
  </table>
```

Here what actually i need is

Accept this order

But i am getting

Accept this order[http://127.0.0.1:8000/crm/orders/accepting/13/647/]

Comment: Your issue is about the style. Remove them and it will work

Comment: If i am removing my style when clicking accept this order its not working i mean its not redirecting to my url

Comment: Can you use JavaScript to log the `href` value of the `a` tag ? to see what is the content

Comment: my goal is when first when we click accept this order it need to redirect to crm/orders/accepting/13/647/ and second is we should not see url beside the accept this order